# mysql query on dob

Tags: sql, mysql

If DOB is given in this porder- 1853-03-12 , then how do we find the youngest person from table bases on this type of data. If the year is same but month is different for 2 persons.

I tried MIN(dob)- it gives me the oldest person and When I tried MAX, it gives me nothing.

Comment: Impossible to answer without details about your table structure. I don't know why MAX gives "nothing" - something worth investigating, I think - but a dirty workaround would always be `ORDER BY dob DESC LIMIT 0,1`

Comment: could you check what is the 'type' of the column? if it's a proper 'date' column then min/max should work accordingly.

Comment: the type of dob is DATE. I am still getting the same value that I was getting before with MIN function. In order to find the youngest , I have to use MAX function.BUt it is not producing result with that query

Comment: Be more specific, give the definition of your tables, sample data and your query. You are doing something wrong and we could try to guess what, but that is tedious, where if we had the data and sql it would be obvious.

Comment: Voted to close since the question was resolved outside stackoverflow (question and 'answer' are not useful to anyone having a similar problem). Question should *not* be closed if the details will be given (what was the problem and what was the solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird, however you can use `ORDER BY dob DESC LIMIT 1`

What's your full query ?

EDIT : resolved by email ^^

Comment: I used it, but still getting the old value

Comment: Definitely weird. What's your tables structure and your query ?

Comment: I cant paste the query here because its a hw and anybody can copy my query from here. I have 2 files and tehre are various columns in it. I am need the youngest dob to restrict my query to perform specific funtion. IF you say, I can email you my query.

Comment: Ok i've received it I take a look.

Answer (score 0):

MAX should usualy do the job. maybe you have any datasets with NULL-value in that column? one thing you could try is to `ORDER BY dob DESC` and `LIMIT 1`.